# Simulink inherit configuration reference in reusable model

Tags: configuration, model, reference, simulink

I have a model_A which I am using in various parent models (Parent_1 and Parent_2). 
Each parent model has a configuration reference.

The problem I am having is that model_A get the configuration reference from the last parent model I configure.

Is there a way that each refence of model_A inherits the configuration refence from the Parent_X in which it is referenced?

In other words is there any option to set the Source location of the dictionary as "inherit" ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution I did was to define a third dictionary for the reusable components with the common parameters and also linking this dictionary agains the dictionaries from the parent objects. To summarise

1. Common Dictionary: with common parameters. Reusable models link against this dictionary
2. Parent Dictionary 1: Has a link to Common + Specific Params
3. Parent Dictionary 2

Hope it helps to other people facing similar problems